# Mocking a base property while testing derived class

Tags: c#, mocking

Assume I have two classes:

```
public class Class { }

public class ClassParser
{
    public virtual string ParsedClass { get; }

    public ClassParser(Class c1)
    {
        ParsedClass = DoParsing(c1);
    }

    private string DoParsing(Class c1)
    {
        return "Class parsed";
    }
}

public class SpecialClassParser : ClassParser
{
    public override string ParsedClass => SwitchIdx();

    private readonly int _suffixIdx;

    public SpecialClassParser(Class c1, int suffixIdx)
        : base(c1)
    {
        _suffixIdx = suffixIdx;
    }

    private string SwitchIdx()
    {
        return _suffixIdx switch
        {
            1 => (base.ParsedClass + " With case 1 suffix"),
            2 => (base.ParsedClass + " With case 2 suffix"),
            _ => null
        };
    }
}
```

With this functionality demonstration:

```
private void DoParsings()
{
    Class c1 = new Class();
    string withClassParser = (new ClassParser(c1)).ParsedClass;
    // "Class parsed"
    string withSpecialClassParser_1 = (new SpecialClassParser(c1, 1)).ParsedClass;
    // "Class parsed With case 1 suffix"
    string withSpecialClassParser_2 = (new SpecialClassParser(c1, 2)).ParsedClass;
    // "Class parsed With case 2 suffix"
}
```

I want to test the derived class property, so that the derived class properly processes the base class property after it is initialized.
I want to be able to mock the base property parsing.

Pseudo code of a mock setup:

```
Mock<SpecialClassParser> specialParser = new Mock<SpecialClassParser>(c1, 1);
specialParser.Setup(p => p.ParsedClass_InBaseClass)
             .Returns("Base class did a lot of calculations on c1 and came up with this parsed string");
```

Is there any way to make it happen?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior) library has `CallBase` property, if you are using this library

Comment: I am using moq. However, I don't want the derived class to call base as it will actually invoke "ProcessInBaseClass" method and process the string. I want to manually set the value that the base class property returns.

Comment: This is a design problem. The current design is poorly thought out and the difficulty encountered in testing it exposes the original underlying code smell. I suggest you review your design choice by first asking why you need to bypass the base class to begin with.

Comment: If this simplified example is not a true representation of the actual problem  Then it would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: I think you should change inheritance to composition in this case, I don't really see any pros of using inheritance here

Comment: Also you can probably take a look at decorator patern

Comment: Thanks for the advice to make my example more understandable. I edited the question with more concrete example.

Comment: @Ohad for clarity, is the demonstration code meant to be a test? If not. Show your current attempt of the test of what you would like it to be. That should help show what you actually want to test.

Comment: It's hard to demonstrate how to test it if I don't know how to write it, if possible. I tried to add a pseudo code of what I wanted the outcome to be.

Comment: @sTrenat I do see how decorator pattern can make this compenent to be more testable. However, I do see a relation of SpecialClassParser is ClassParser which made me prefer inheritance.

Comment: @Ohad I get it now based on your updates, but now that everything has been cleared up , my original statement about it being a design issue still stand. You would need to make the base member virtual so that it can be overridden for testing, which is still a code smell since that member is invoked in the constructor. This will still invoke the base before you are able to override it in the mock.

Comment: maybe create Interface that both classes derive from?

Comment: @Nkosi I understand, but it is private for a purpose. I don't want derived classes to override the way the ClassParser does it's parsings. I just want them to able to present the parsed string in any way they desire.

Comment: @Ohad then there is an issue here with SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and separation of Concerns (SoC).

Comment: I see why it seems smelly to you. After all the comments here I assume it is not possible with moq library (I meanwhile found it's possible with commerial libraries). Primary reason it's smelly, I guess, Is because it is not testable or at least hard to test. However, for some reason it still seems to me like a "Derived is Base" relationship is a better fit here since they both expose the same functionality and also, both are parsers.